# Any performance impact in Oracle for using LIKE 'string' vs = 'string'?

Tags: sql, performance, oracle

This

```
SELECT * FROM SOME_TABLE WHERE SOME_FIELD LIKE '%some_value%';
```

is slower than this

```
SELECT * FROM SOME_TABLE WHERE SOME_FIELD = 'some_value';
```

but what about this?

```
SELECT * FROM SOME_TABLE WHERE SOME_FIELD LIKE 'some_value';
```

My testing indicates the second and third examples are exactly the same.  If that's true, my question is, why ever use "=" ?

Comment: 1 - Ran a statement against a large table using both methods many times, noting the execution time

2 - Looked at the explain plan

Answer (score 21, accepted):

There is a clear difference when you use bind variables, which you should be using in Oracle for anything other than data warehousing or other bulk data operations.

Take the case of:

```
SELECT * FROM SOME_TABLE WHERE SOME_FIELD LIKE :b1
```

Oracle cannot know that the value of :b1 is '%some_value%', or 'some_value' etc. until execution time, so it will make an estimation of the cardinality of the result based on heuristics and come up with an appropriate plan that either may or may not be suitable for various values of :b, such as '%A','%', 'A' etc.

Similar issues can apply with an equality predicate but the range of cardinalities that might result is much more easily estimated based on column statistics or the presence of a unique constraint, for example.

So, personally I wouldn't start using LIKE as a replacement for =. The optimizer is pretty easy to fool sometimes.

Comment: Good answer!  It seemed foolish when I read the question, but I couldn't put my finger on exactly why.  This is the correct answer.

Answer (score 5):

Check out the [EXPLAIN PLAN](http://www.adp-gmbh.ch/ora/explainplan.html) for both. They generate the same execution plan, so to the database, they're the same thing.

You would use = to test for equality, not similarity.  If you're controlling the comparison value as well, then it doesn't make much of a difference.  If that's being submitted by a user, then 'apple' and 'apple%' would give you much different results.

Comment: For very large tables, there might be a noticeable performance difference between the LIKE test and = even if the plan is identical.  But it's best to test.

Comment: Yeah, if you use bind variable, as you should, the optimizer doesn't really know what you're going to pass to it. So, it can't necessarily optimize for having a wild card on just one side. (Of course Oracle may have worked around that characteristic).

Answer (score 3):

> If that's true, my question is, why
>   ever use "=" ?

A better question: If that's true, why use "LIKE" to test for equality?  You get to save hitting the shift key, and everyone who reads the script gets to be confused.

Answer (score 2):

Have you tried it?  Testing is the only sure way to know.

As an aside, none of these statements are certain to return the same rows.  Try out:

```
insert into some_table (some_field) values ('some_value');
insert into some_table (some_fieled) values ('1some_value2');
insert into some_table (some_field) values ('some1value');

SELECT * FROM SOME_TABLE WHERE SOME_FIELD LIKE '%some_value%';

SELECT * FROM SOME_TABLE WHERE SOME_FIELD = 'some_value';

SELECT * FROM SOME_TABLE WHERE SOME_FIELD LIKE 'some_value';
```

In terms of clarity and to avoid subtle bugs, it's best to never use **LIKE** unless you need it's wildcard functionality.  (Obviously, when doing ad-hoc queries, it's probably alright.)

Comment: what's the difference in results look like? i don't have access to a sandbox server to test your example.

Comment: `LIKE '%some_value%'` returns all three records, `= 'some_value'` returns only the second record, `LIKE 'some_value'` returns the first and third records.

Comment: LIKE 'some_value' returns the first and third records.  = 'some_value' also returns those same records.  logically, they will always return the same record set.  IIRC when I wrote this question, I was generating some dynamic sql, and i was annoyed at having to conditionally supply an "=" or "LIKE" based on options the user chose.  Since they are going to always return the same results, I was wondering if there was a downside to just using LIKE.  David Aldridge's answer pointed out good reasons why.

Comment: @JosephStyons: `WHERE some_field = 'some_value'` **doesn't** return `some1value` as `LIKE 'some_value'` does, as for `LIKE` the underscore is a placeholder for any character. For equals it is a literal of course and therefore won't return that record. Try it out.

Answer (score 1):

LIKE '%WHATEVER%' will have to do a full index scan.

If there is not percent, then it acts like an equals.

If the % is on one end, then the index can be a range scan.

I'm not sure how the optimizer handles bound fields.

Answer (score 1):

`like` is formally the same if you do not have characters like `$%` etc so it is not a big surprise to find that it has the same cost.

I find David Aldridge answer interesting as your application should be using bind variables. With a `like '%foobar'` you cannot make use of ordering in the index. If the query is pre-compiled It will lead to more index or table full Scans.

Furthermore, I find it dangerous as it can lead to SQL Injections and strange bugs ( for example, if there is a user called john a hacker can create a user named `'joh$'` and try to log in)

why take the risk? `'='` is clearer and has none of those problems.

Answer (score 0):

1) % and = are intended to be used in different scenarios. 
Even though we can search with exact value in like clause and get the desired result, one should still be using = in all such scenarios. Therefore whenever we have exact value to be searched we always should be using =.

2) performance of like and = whenever no % is provided in search clause:
In all such cases, query optimizer automatically converts like cluase to =. And this can be  evident from query plan (Please see screenshots attached) . Therefore performance should be exactly the same  in this case. Thanks to query optimizer!

I am providing the screenshots of the execution plans of both the queries i.e. query with like clause but without % and  query with like clause and with %.

[image: like Cluase with % query execution plan]

[image: like clause without % query execution plan]

Comment: Thank you for your detailed and thoughtful response.  Please know that I was sort of playing devil's advocate with this question; it definitely "feels" wrong to use LIKE when you mean "=".  Having said that - doesn't your answer actually suggest that using LIKE is fine?  If the optimizer deals with it the same way, then there is no performance impact, and no functional impact- so whats the point of an "="?