# Oracle where clause that matches all entries

Tags: sql, oracle

Is there a way to construct a parametrised query with a where clause on a field that matches all entries in the field. For example I am imagining syntax like

```
'select brands from cars where brands = param'
```

such that if `param = 'Toyota'` then it only returns rows matching Toyota, but if `param = *` it returns all rows from the `cars` table.

Comment: You mean just not adding the `where` clause filter at all?

Comment: It would be acceptable if it is possible to dynamically not add the where clause filter if brands is not specified.

Answer (score 3):

Try this. It's a conditional `WHERE` clause

```
WHERE brands = NVL(param, brands)
```

Means if the param is `NULL`, use `brands = brands`

Comment: will this be faster than `where brands like %`? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31931258/oracle-where-clause-that-matches-all-entries/31931380#31931380

Comment: You need to always check it in execution plan https://blogs.oracle.com/optimizer/entry/displaying_and_reading_the_execution_plans_for_a_sql_statement

Comment: Check out this one too http://stackoverflow.com/questions/134456/any-performance-impact-in-oracle-for-using-like-string-vs-string

Comment: can this construct be used with `IN` and `= ANY` clauses as well?

Answer (score 2):

```
select * from cars where brands like '%'||parameter||'%'
```

You can use `distinct` to get all brands from your table.

Comment: Please see the edit on the question. I specifically need something like `where  brands = *` so that I can pass a null argument or a specified argument to it.

Answer (score 2):

The usual workaround is

```
select brands from cars where brands LIKE param
```

If param = 'Toyota' it returns only Toyota

If param = '%' it returns everything

Simple but not necessarily performant.

Comment: Will this have any side effects, e.g. matching things like `Toyota2`?

Comment: Only if you pass in `Toyota_` or `Toyota%`

Comment: thanks, this is very slow on my database, as you predicted. I wonder whether the solution http://stackoverflow.com/a/31931369/2109289 is faster

Comment: Yes that solution is quite likely to be faster. Try it and see. Compare execution plans

Answer (score 1):

If you have a variable, you would do:

```
where v_brand is null or v_brand = brand
```

If you just want an expression that matches everything:

```
where 1 = 1
```

Answer (score 1):

The proper way to return all rows regardless of `brand` is to remove the `brands = param` from your filter, not to use a wildcards or functions on it...

It is common to add `where 1=1` to clauses in your case and use in the following pattern:

If `param` has a value

```
select brands from cars where 1=1 and brands = param
```

otherwise you just remove the `and brands = param` part:

```
select brands from cars where 1=1
```