# Optimization of text parsing - Oracle SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, sql-like

I am working on a SQL query that will count the appearances of certain words in "long text", or a huge text field that is a `CLOB` data type.

My dataset (which is massive, ~5M+ rows) looks something like this:

http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/2c13d/1

I have a query, like this:

```
SELECT
  TheTask AS Tasking,
  SUM(CASE WHEN TRIM(UPPER(TheTaskText)) LIKE '%LONG%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS LongCount,
  SUM(CASE WHEN TRIM(UPPER(TheTaskText)) LIKE '%TEXT%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS TextCount,
  SUM(CASE WHEN TRIM(UPPER(TheTaskText)) LIKE '%ENGLISH%' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS EnglishCount
FROM
  example
GROUP BY
  TheTask
```

However, it takes an extremely long time to run on the complete dataset (~3 hours or so). I believe this is due to [LIKE optimization issues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134456/any-performance-impact-in-oracle-for-using-like-string-vs-string), but I am unsure of how else to achieve this goal dataset. I have tried researching other articles on [how to optimize like](https://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/where-clause/searching-for-ranges/like-performance-tuning), but is it possible that `REGEX` or something would be quicker? I am looking to optimize this query by evaluating `LIKE` performance.

Comment: [Full Text index](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/text.111/b28303/ind.htm#g1020588)

Comment: I don't know what that is.

Comment: `LIKE '%sth' is not SARGable so it has poor performance. If you really need to search text then FTI is what you need.

Comment: Are the words different each time you run a query? If not, you can count them when you insert a row (with a tirgger, f.e.) and use separate columns to store the values.

Comment: The problem is I am working on a historical dataset, I have no control over any 'W' permissions to the database application @PavelSmirnov

Comment: I think that with the wildcard character in the LIKE, the TRIM() only adds overhead.

Comment: I often see questions like this that say it takes hours to search a few million rows. That should never be the case. I can search a few million rows on my laptop in _seconds_, so you should be able to do it much faster on a server. I don't want this to sound elitist or mean, but have you considered that your server is too underpowered for the job you are trying to do?

Comment: @BillKarwin not elitist or mean at all. There are obviously other factors that come into play; server hardware, network bandwidth, etc etc. And that absolutely factors into the "time" it takes for results to show. I would need to build a case around why it is those factors, and not my code, which is why I am looking to SO for feedback on other methods (or a confirmation that `LIKE` is an appropriate solution) of how to improve the `SQL`, as it will obviously be the first step. I am even trying to do a run-time complexity analysis.

Comment: Well your query is of course doing a table-scan, reading 100% of the 5 million rows, but honestly that's not that large. Oracle should be able to handle that without any significant effort, unless you're running it on a server that is very old, or else you have so many processes running that the system load is too high, or it's using swap instead of RAM.

Comment: @BillKarwin This could be an exception to the millions-of-rows-isn't-large-anymore rule.  Since the column is a CLOB data type, each value could theoretically contain gigabytes of data.  @Jerry M. - Can you measure the size of these CLOBs in bytes with SQL like this?  `select bytes/1024/1024/1024 gb
from dba_segments where segment_name in
(
 select segment_name
 from dba_lobs
 where column_name = 'THETASKTEXT'
);`.

Comment: That's true, I didn't account for the possibility that each row would be huge. The OP didn't describe the total size. That's the problem with using subjective descriptions like "massive."

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `CONTEXT` index type is used to index long texts. You can use :

`CREATE INDEX idx_TheTaskTxt ON example(TRIM(UPPER(TheTaskText))) INDEXTYPE IS CTXSYS.CONTEXT;`

and collect statistics for the optimizer to take effect :

`EXEC DBMS_STATS.GATHER_TABLE_STATS(USER, 'EXAMPLE', cascade=>TRUE);`

and call

```
SELECT
  TheTask AS Tasking,
  SUM(CASE WHEN CONTAINS(TRIM(UPPER(TheTaskText)), 'LONG', 1) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS LongCount,
  SUM(CASE WHEN CONTAINS(TRIM(UPPER(TheTaskText)), 'TEXT', 1) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS TextCount,
  SUM(CASE WHEN CONTAINS(TRIM(UPPER(TheTaskText)), 'ENGLISH', 1) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) AS EnglishCount
FROM example
GROUP BY TheTask
HAVING 
       SUM(CASE WHEN CONTAINS(TRIM(UPPER(TheTaskText)), 'LONG', 1) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) * 
       SUM(CASE WHEN CONTAINS(TRIM(UPPER(TheTaskText)), 'TEXT', 1) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) *
       SUM(CASE WHEN CONTAINS(TRIM(UPPER(TheTaskText)), 'ENGLISH', 1) > 0 THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) 
       IN (0,1)
```