# SQL "LIKE" and "IN" operators

Tags: sql, oracle

What is the difference between operators "LIKE" and "IN" in oracle sql ?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/134456/any-performance-impact-in-oracle-for-using-like-string-vs-string

Comment: Just read about the two. More precise question would be what they have in common...

Comment: @Sanzhar . . . Pretty much the same as it is in any other database.

Answer (score 0):

The `LIKE` operator is for simple string pattern matching. For example:

```
SELECT column1 FROM table1 WHERE string_column LIKE 'ABC%';
```

The `IN` operator checks for a match in a list of values. For example:

```
SELECT column1 FROM table1 WHERE string_column IN ('This', 'That');
SELECT column1 FROM table1 WHERE fk_column IN (SELECT id FROM table2);
```

For additional reading, here are the [docs for LIKE](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/Pattern-matching-Conditions.html#GUID-3FA7F5AB-AC64-4200-8F90-294101428C26) and the [docs for IN](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/12.2/sqlrf/IN-Condition.html#GUID-C7961CB3-8F60-47E0-96EB-BDCF5DB1317C).

Answer (score 0):

```
select * from t where col like '%MATCH_1%';
```

selects all rows where the column contains "MATCH", then any character, then "1".

```
select * from t where col like 'PREFIX%';
```

selects all rows where the column has a prefix of "PREFIX".

```
select * from t where col like '%APPENDIX';
```

selects all rows where the column ends with "APPENDIX".

```
select * from t where col IN (1,10,20);
```

selects all rows where the column has one of the values in the list. The list must not be empty.

So the IN operator is quite different from LIKE.

Answer (score 0):

**IN** statement creates a series of OR statements like

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column IN (a, b, c) 

-- Which also means

SELECT * FROM table WHERE column = a OR column = b OR column = c
```

When using **LIKE**, we are looking for a resemblance:

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column LIKE '%Text%'
```

with like you can manipulate the statement to suite many scenarios i.e. [w3 school](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_like.asp)

```
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column LIKE '%Text%' --Finds any values that has Text
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column LIKE 'Text%'  --Finds any values that start with Text
SELECT * FROM table WHERE column LIKE '%Text'  --Finds any values that ends with Text
```

The answer to this question is wide and depends on **use-case**. If you come up with a **use-case** the better.

Answer (score 0):

if you use LIKE you use a PATTERN, 
which is used to get data of the select:

```
SELECT salary 
FROM employees
WHERE last_name LIKE 'R%';
```

In case of you of IN you define a LIST OF VALUES,
which is used to get data:

```
SELECT salary 
FROM employees
WHERE last_name in ( 'Richard', 'Richardson)';
```

with kind regards